# Track hovered elements and ignore rest in certain time frame

Tags: jquery

When I hover over `.first` element and if none other has class `.open` I want to add that class immediately and show its child list, if not I want to wait `600ms`. 
The whole logic is I want to ignore hovering on siblings of `.first` for those `600ms`, so if one is active and I hover over any sibling and if I move back in that time frame I want to still show the originals child list.

With my current attempt I get a flashing switheroo show:

```js
$('.first').hover(function(){
    var cEle = $(this);
    if($('.first.open').length > 0){
      setTimeout(function(){ 
        if($(cEle).hover()){
          $('.first.open').removeClass('open');
          $(cEle).addClass('open');
        }
      }, 600);
    }
    else{
      $(this).addClass('open');
    }

});
```

```css
.menu{float:left; width:450px; margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; list-style:none;}
.first{float:left; width:150px; text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0; background:white; position:relative;}
.first:hover{background:#ccc;}
.inner{float:left; width:450px; margin:0; padding:0; display:none; position:absolute; left:0; top:100%; background:#e8e8e8;}
.inner li{float:left; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
/*.first:hover .inner{display:block;}*/

.first.open .inner{display:block;}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="first">Item
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>i-item</li>
      <li>i-item</li>
      <li>i-item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="first">Item
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>i-item</li>
      <li>i-item</li>
      <li>i-item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="first">Item
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>i-item</li>
      <li>i-item</li>
      <li>i-item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please use Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button) for your runnable examples, not off-site resources. [Here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). Please also take the time to use proper capitalization and punctuation when asking other people for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer mouseenter and mouseleave events for this and make use of the clearTimeout to destroy setTimeout whenever the mouse leaves the menu entry

**UPDATED: Provide a closing timer after a specific time as requested by the comment**

```js
var timer = null;
var closeTimer = null;
var closeTimeout = 600;

function openMenu(el) {
   $('.first').removeClass('open');
   $(el).addClass('open');
}

$('.first').mouseleave(function() {
    if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
    closeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        $('.first').removeClass('open');
    }, closeTimeout);
});

$('.first').mouseenter(function(){
   if(closeTimer) clearTimeout(closeTimer);
   var cEle = this;
   if($('.first.open').length > 0) {
       timer = setTimeout(function(){ 
          openMenu(cEle);
       }, 600);
   } else {
       openMenu(cEle);
   }
});
```

```css
.menu{float:left; width:450px; margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; list-style:none;}
.first{float:left; width:150px; text-align:center; margin:0; padding:0; background:white; position:relative;}
.first:hover{background:#ccc;}
.inner{float:left; width:450px; margin:0; padding:0; display:none; position:absolute; left:0; top:100%; background:#e8e8e8;}
.inner li{float:left; width:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}
/*.first:hover .inner{display:block;}*/

.first.open .inner{display:block;}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="first">Item
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>i-item</li>
      <li>i-item</li>
      <li>i-item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="first">Item
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>i-item</li>
      <li>i-item</li>
      <li>i-item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="first">Item
    <ul class="inner">
      <li>i-item</li>
      <li>i-item</li>
      <li>i-item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Solved the sturreing between two or multiple but it doesnt close when you exit all for a certain time